# MVC Autologin from another website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autologin

I have 2 MVC web apps, lets call it MVC_A and MVC_B.

I want to be able to login to MVC_A through a link which is on MVC_B.

I have on MVC_B a page with some text on it and a link to MVC_A. When users click this link, they should automaticly login on MVC_A in another tab of their browser.

Keep in mind that for both apps I have different User tables (with hashed passwords).

Is this possible to do? And if so, could you tell me which way I have to go to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you share the same database or if you can access the database of MVC_A from MVC_B i suggest the following:

1. Change all your links from MVC_A to MVC_B pages from http://MVC_B/etc... to /redir?url=....&sessionid=...
2. In the `redir` page, generate a unique SessionID in the database, assigned to the currect user name. You should use a table similar to: [ID, UserName, SessionID (Guid maybe?), Used]. Then redirect to the MVC_B page with the generated SessionID in QS (Ex: http://MVC_B/url?sessionid=...).
3. In the MVC_B, when you have sessionid in QS, read the UserName from the database based on the SessionID just received, mark the SessionID as `used` (so it cannot be used again) and authenticate it (if you have an user with the same UserName in the database).

Comment: thanks for your info. I was thinking about a table which shorlty holds some information about the user so I understand your approach. But how can I authenticate to MVC_A with only a Username?

Comment: you should manually create the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and then the authentication cookie. Then add it with `Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)`. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET (`Submit1_Click` method) on how to achieve this.